# Looking for a Spider-Man comic from the 1970s where a telepathic man-child controls a town, is defeated when Spidey "deafens" him?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, spider-man

**Plot Details/Summary**

The villain in this one was a man who had been born something of mutant (in a more traditional, non X-Men sense of the word).  He looked rather freakish/monstrous, and possessed mental powers.  There is some exposition in the story about everyone (including his family) fearing him when from the time he was a little boy, and something about him causing the death of one or both of his parents by mentally forcing them to run out in front of a moving car.

I don't recall how Spider-Man runs afoul of the villain, but I do recall the mutant having most of the townspeople under his mental control.  He sends them to attack Spider-Man, swarming him.   I think the cover of the issue might have a similar scene. I think Spider-Man also faces direct mental assault by the villain, but am not sure.

Spider-Man is saved when he recalls something the villain had said about the people "hearing his thoughts" or something like that.  He claps the villain-mutant on the ears, deafening him and breaking his control on the townspeople.   I believe the story ends with the villain whimpering and pitifully begging the people to listen to him. Something like that.

**Publication Details**

I read it in the mid-to-late 1970s, and I'm almost certain it was a regular Spider-Man comic, not a spin-off title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The villain you're referring to is [Mindworm](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/William_Turner_(Earth-616)).

He made his first appearance in *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #138](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_138)*, which appears to be the issue you described in your question. As you noted, his telepathic control over the hundreds of civilians in the area was broken when Spider-Man boxed his ears, temporarily deafening him.

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow - if only the Second Foundation had a Spider-Man, they could have easily defeated the Mule so many years quicker than they did. Just punch him in the ears!

Comment: Brr! That guy *still* gives me the creeps.   What a freaky looking villain!